# How to apply pos_tag_sents() to pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk, pos-tagger

In situations where you wish to POS tag a column of text stored in a pandas dataframe with 1 sentence per row the majority of implementations on SO use the apply method

```
dfData['POSTags']= dfData['SourceText'].apply(
                 lamda row: [pos_tag(word_tokenize(row) for item in row])
```

The NLTK documentation [recommends using the pos_tag_sents()](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.pos_tag) for efficient tagging of more than one sentence.

Does that apply to this example and if so would the code be as simple as changing `pso_tag` to `pos_tag_sents` or does NLTK mean text sources of paragraphs

As mentioned in the comments `pos_tag_sents()` aims to reduce the loading of the preceptor each time **but the issue is how to do this and still produce a column in a pandas dataframe?**

[Link to Sample Dataset 20kRows](http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/1ec7e9ad579c3e0a4eb5fa7c16164c6d/20kSampleTextData.csv)

Comment: how many rows do you have?

Comment: 20,000 rows would be the number of rows

Comment: That's not a problem. Just extract the column as a list of strings, process it and then add to the column back to to the dataframe.

Comment: Could you provide a coded example?

Comment: Could you provide the data example? Just dump your dataframe.head() into a csv file ;P

Comment: Added a link to a sample csv file now

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat test.csv 
ID,Task,label,Text
1,Collect Information,no response,cozily married practical athletics Mr. Brown flat
2,New Credit,no response,active married expensive soccer Mr. Chang flat
3,Collect Information,response,healthy single expensive badminton Mrs. Green flat
4,Collect Information,response,cozily married practical soccer Mr. Brown hierachical
5,Collect Information,response,cozily single practical badminton Mr. Brown flat
```

**TL;DR**

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
>>> df['Text']
0    cozily married practical athletics Mr. Brown flat
1       active married expensive soccer Mr. Chang flat
2    healthy single expensive badminton Mrs. Green ...
3    cozily married practical soccer Mr. Brown hier...
4     cozily single practical badminton Mr. Brown flat
Name: Text, dtype: object
>>> texts = df['Text'].tolist()
>>> tagged_texts = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, texts))
>>> tagged_texts
[[('cozily', 'RB'), ('married', 'JJ'), ('practical', 'JJ'), ('athletics', 'NNS'), ('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Brown', 'NNP'), ('flat', 'JJ')], [('active', 'JJ'), ('married', 'VBD'), ('expensive', 'JJ'), ('soccer', 'NN'), ('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Chang', 'NNP'), ('flat', 'JJ')], [('healthy', 'JJ'), ('single', 'JJ'), ('expensive', 'JJ'), ('badminton', 'NN'), ('Mrs.', 'NNP'), ('Green', 'NNP'), ('flat', 'JJ')], [('cozily', 'RB'), ('married', 'JJ'), ('practical', 'JJ'), ('soccer', 'NN'), ('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Brown', 'NNP'), ('hierachical', 'JJ')], [('cozily', 'RB'), ('single', 'JJ'), ('practical', 'JJ'), ('badminton', 'NN'), ('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Brown', 'NNP'), ('flat', 'JJ')]]

>>> df['POS'] = tagged_texts
>>> df
   ID                 Task        label  \
0   1  Collect Information  no response   
1   2           New Credit  no response   
2   3  Collect Information     response   
3   4  Collect Information     response   
4   5  Collect Information     response   

                                                Text  \
0  cozily married practical athletics Mr. Brown flat   
1     active married expensive soccer Mr. Chang flat   
2  healthy single expensive badminton Mrs. Green ...   
3  cozily married practical soccer Mr. Brown hier...   
4   cozily single practical badminton Mr. Brown flat   

                                                 POS  
0  [(cozily, RB), (married, JJ), (practical, JJ),...  
1  [(active, JJ), (married, VBD), (expensive, JJ)...  
2  [(healthy, JJ), (single, JJ), (expensive, JJ),...  
3  [(cozily, RB), (married, JJ), (practical, JJ),...  
4  [(cozily, RB), (single, JJ), (practical, JJ), ...
```

---

**In Long:**

First, you can extract the `Text` column to a list of string:

```
texts = df['Text'].tolist()
```

Then you can apply the `word_tokenize` function:

```
map(word_tokenize, texts)
```

Note that, @Boud's suggested is almost the same, using `df.apply`:

```
df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

Then you dump the tokenized text into a list of list of string:

```
df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist()
```

Then you can use `pos_tag_sents`:

```
pos_tag_sents( df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist() )
```

Then you add the column back to the DataFrame:

```
df['POS'] = pos_tag_sents( df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist() )
```

Comment: Your 'TL;DR' is longer than the 'In Long' version :)

Comment: @Louis Yang  -- Funny! And, yes, longer than the 'In Long' section. But I just stepped though it and works exactly.

Answer (score 3):

By applying `pos_tag` on each row, the Perceptron model will be loaded each time (costly operation, as it reads a pickle from disk).

If you instead get all the rows and send them to `pos_tag_sents` (which takes `list(list(str))`), the model is loaded once and used for all.

See the [source](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag.html#pos_tag_sents).

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example to use `pos_tag_sents()` with a pandas dataframe column as the source and overall destination so that the sentence and tagged output are on the same row?

Comment: I would be stabbing in the dark, as I'm not that familiar with Pandas. Maybe something like `pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, dfData['SourceText'].values()))`.

Answer (score 2):

Assign this to your new column instead:

```
dfData['POSTags'] = pos_tag_sents(dfData['SourceText'].apply(word_tokenize).tolist())
```