# how to resolve the error: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, nltk, preprocessor, wordnet, lemmatization

When I'm trying to run this code to preprocess a text, I get the error below, someone is having a similar problem but the post did not have enough details.

I am putting everything in context here hoping to help reviewer to help us better.

Here is the function;

```
def preprocessing(text):
    #text=text.decode("utf8")
    #tokenize into words
    tokens=[word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in 
    nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
    #remove stopwords
    stop=stopwords.words('english')
    tokens=[token for token in tokens if token not in stop]
    #remove words less than three letters
    tokens=[word for word in tokens if len(word)>=3]
    #lower capitalization
    tokens=[word.lower() for word in tokens]
    #lemmatization
    lmtzr=WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word for word in tokens)]
    preprocessed_text=' '.join(tokens)
    return preprocessed_text
```

## calling the function here;

```
#open the text data from disk location
sms=open('C:/Users/Ray/Documents/BSU/Machine_learning/Natural_language_Processing_Pyhton_And_NLTK_Chap6/smsspamcollection/SMSSpamCollection')
sms_data=[]
sms_labels=[]
csv_reader=csv.reader(sms,delimiter='\t')
for line in csv_reader:
    #adding the sms_id
    sms_labels.append(line[0])
    #adding the cleaned text by calling the preprocessing method
    sms_data.append(preprocessing(line[1]))
sms.close()
```

result;

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-38-b42d443adaa6> in <module>()
      8     sms_labels.append(line[0])
      9     #adding the cleaned text by calling the preprocessing method
---> 10     sms_data.append(preprocessing(line[1]))
     11 sms.close()

<ipython-input-37-69ef4cd83745> in preprocessing(text)
     12     #lemmatization
     13     lmtzr=WordNetLemmatizer()
---> 14     tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word for word in tokens)]
     15     preprocessed_text=' '.join(tokens)
     16     return preprocessed_text

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py in lemmatize(self, word, pos)
     38 
     39     def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):
---> 40         lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
     41         return min(lemmas, key=len) if lemmas else word
     42 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in
_morphy(self, form, pos, check_exceptions)    1798     1799         # 1. Apply rules once to the input to get y1, y2, y3, etc.
-> 1800         forms = apply_rules([form])    1801     1802         # 2. Return all that are in the database (and check the original too)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in apply_rules(forms)    1777         def apply_rules(forms):    1778     return [form[:-len(old)] + new
-> 1779                     for form in forms    1780                     for old, new in substitutions    1781                     if form.endswith(old)]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in <listcomp>(.0)    1779                     for form in forms    1780   for old, new in substitutions
-> 1781                     if form.endswith(old)]    1782     1783         def filter_forms(forms):

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I believe the error is coming from the source code for nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet

The whole source code can be seen in the nltk documentation page. It's too long to post here; but below is the raw [link](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html):

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're passing a generator here: `tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word  for word in tokens)]` - does this method actually accept a generator? did you mean  `tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word)  for word in tokens]`

Comment: Heh, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe/47788736#47788736 and understand why your preprocessing is sub-optimal because it's iterating through the tokens multiple times... Could I ask where did you get this code sample from? This code sample is haunting people and you're not the first one to ask a question based on this.

Comment: Yes the code is from chapter6 (text classification) of the book "Natural Language Processing Python And NLTK" by Hardeniya Et Al.

Comment: Yes the code is from chapter6 (text classification) of the book "Natural Language Processing Python And NLTK" by Hardeniya Et Al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message and traceback points you to the source of the problem:

> in preprocessing(text) 12 #lemmatization 13 lmtzr=WordNetLemmatizer()
>   ---> 14 tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word for word in tokens)] 15 preprocessed_text=' '.join(tokens) 16 return preprocessed_text
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py in lemmatize(self,
>   word, pos) 38 39 def lemmatize(self, word, pos=NOUN):

Obviously, from the function's signature (`word`, not `words`) and the error ("has no attribute 'endswith'" - `endswith()` is actually a `str` method), `lemmatize()` expects a single word, but here:

```
tokens=[lmtzr.lemmatize(word for word in tokens)]
```

you are passing a generator expression.

What you want is:

```
tokens = [lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens]
```

NB : you mentions:

> I believe the error is coming from the source code for
>   nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet

The error is indeed *raised* in this package, but it "is coming from" (in the sense of "caused by") your code passing the wrong argument ;)

Hope this will help you debug this kind of problems by yourself next time.

Comment: `str.endswith()` accepts a tuple, would that work here like `lmtzr.lemmatize(tuple(tokens))]` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands obviously not. Reread the call stack and look how `str.endswith()` is called (hint: it's a method called on a str instance - actually the word passed to `.lemmatize()`). If you passed a `tuple`, `endswith()` would be called on that tuple (just as it's been called on the generator in the OP's code), and raised the same AttributeError because `tuple` has no attribute `endswith()` either. TL;DR : `.lemmatize()` expects a string, give it a string, else it will fail.

Comment: Ah yes, point taken, I should have looked more carefully, agreed!

Comment: Thank you Bruno for the input, the problem was the argument.