# Apply a function to each element of a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I am trying to tokenize each sentence of my `pandas` series.
I try to do as I see in the documentation, using apply, but didn't work:

```
x.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
```

If I just use `nltk.word_tokenize(x)` didn't work too, because `x` is not a string. Does someone have any idea?

Edited: `x` is a `pandas` series with sentences:

```
0       A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie ...
1       Not sure who was more lost - the flat characte...
2       Attempting artiness with black & white and cle...
```

With `x.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)` it returns exactly the same:

```
0       A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie ...
1       Not sure who was more lost - the flat characte...
2       Attempting artiness with black & white and cle...
```

With `nltk.word_tokenize(x)` the error is:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: When you say it didn't work, are you getting an error? If so could you paste the error here? Also a very small example of what `x` is would be helpful

Comment: It you were to run `print(x.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)` this returns the same result?

Comment: If nltk.word_tokenize(x) gives you TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - It could be the case that you have null values.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe

Comment: what's your output of `type(x)`?

Comment: @Carolina Bury a minimum viable sample of your code that produces the error would go a long way toward us being able to answer your question. = )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question:** are you saving your intermediate results? `x.apply()` creates a copy of your original `Series` with the appropriate transformations applied to each element of the `Series`. See below for an example of how this might be affecting your code...

We'll start by confirming that `word_tokenize()` works on a sample snippet of text.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize('hello how are you')   # confirming that word_tokenize works.
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Then let's create a `Series` to play with.

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['hello how are you',
                   'lorem ipsum isumming lorems',
                   'more stuff in a line'])

>>> print(s)
0              hello how are you
1    lorem ipsum isumming lorems
2           more stuff in a line
dtype: object
```

Executing `word_tokenize` using the `apply()` function on an interactive Python prompt shows that it tokenizes...

But doesn't indicate that this is a copy... not a permanent change to `s`

```
>>> s.apply(word_tokenize)
0              [hello, how, are, you]
1    [lorem, ipsum, isumming, lorems]
2          [more, stuff, in, a, line]
dtype: object
```

In fact, we can print `s` to show that it is unchanged...

```
>>> print(s)
0              hello how are you
1    lorem ipsum isumming lorems
2           more stuff in a line
dtype: object
```

If, instead, we supply a label, in this case `wt` to the results of the `apply()` function call it allows us to save the results permanently. Which we can see by printing `wt`.

```
>>> wt = s.apply(word_tokenize)
>>> print(wt)
0              [hello, how, are, you]
1    [lorem, ipsum, isumming, lorems]
2          [more, stuff, in, a, line]
dtype: object
```

Doing this on an interactive prompt allows us to more easily detect such a condition, but running it in a script sometimes means that the fact that a copy was produced will pass silently and without indication.

Answer (score 0):

The apply call should work fine. I tried your code and it working fine for me. Can you share the exact code which you are using

```
    In [16]: s
    Out[16]:
    0     A very, very, very slow-moving, aimless movie
    1    Not sure who was more lost - the flat characte
    dtype: object

    In [17]: s.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
    Out[17]:
    0    [A, very, ,, very, ,, very, slow-moving, ,, ai...
    1    [Not, sure, who, was, more, lost, -, the, flat...
    dtype: object
```