# How to tokenize every sentence into indivdual words in row of dataframe and average the polarity for every word in sentence?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, textblob

I have a df that looks like this:

```
       text
0   Thanks, I’ll have a read!
1   Am I too late
```

How do I apply TextBlob tokenization to every word in sentence and average the polarity scores of every word in each sentence?

for example, I can do this with a single sentence in a variable:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import import statistics as s

#tokenize word in sentence
a = TextBlob("""Thanks, I'll have a read!""")
print a.words

    WordList(['Thanks', 'I', "'ll", 'have', 'a', 'read'])

#get polarity of every word
    for i in a.words:
        print( a.sentiment.polarity)

    0.25
    0.25
    0.25
    0.25
    0.25
    0.25


#calculating the mean of the scores
c=[]
for i in a.words: 
    c.append(a.sentiment.polarity)
    d = s.mean(c)
    print (d)

0.25
```

How do I apply the `a.words` to every row of dataframe column for sentence?

New df:

```
      text                        score
0   Thanks, I’ll have a read!      0.25
1   Am I too late                  0.24
```

closet I come is that I can get polarity of every sentence using this function on the dataframe:

```
def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity
    except:
        return None

df_sentences['sentiment'] = df_sentences['text'].apply(sentiment_calc)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So `sentiment_calc` not working? I get `0.25` and `-0.3`

Comment: @jezrael `sentiment_calc` is not working the way I want it. `0.25` is the correct answer. I need the for loop for calculating average applied to the `df`

Comment: Yes, but `mean` is not what need, because always returned same value `for i in a.words:
        print( a.sentiment.polarity)`. And it is same for each sentence. So there has to be soemthing wrong, no idea what

Comment: @jezrael good point, I am not sure what is wrong either.

Comment: hmmm, nltk is hard for me, no idea.

Comment: Could you atleast show me how to apply the for loop to the df? I can work on why the tokenization is not working and post answer

Comment: I think `df_sentences['sentiment'] = df_sentences['text'].apply(sentiment_calc)` is good way.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe ?

Comment: @alvas I have not but that is exactly what I am looking for.