# Unhashable type: 'list' error for stopwords

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, data-analysis, stop-words

Here is my code

URL to CSV file: https://github.com/eugeneketeni/web-mining-final-project/blob/master/Test_file.csv

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eugeneketeni/web- 
mining-final-project/master/Test_file.csv")

import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize


data['text'] = data.loc[:, 'text'].astype(str)

text = data.loc[:, "text"].astype(str)
tokenizer = [word_tokenize(text[i]) for i in range(len(text))]
print(tokenizer)

filtered_sentence = []


from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

filtered_sentence = [w for w in tokenizer if not w in stopwords]
print(filtered_sentence)
```

My tokenizer works but when I try to remove the default stopwords, I keep getting "unhashable type: 'list'" error. I am not sure what really going on. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what is tokenizer or the type? I believe it must be a list of list of strings.

Comment: type(tokenizer) is a list

Comment: What are the types of the elements of tokenizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import pandas as pd

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english'))

data = pd.read_csv("Test_file.csv")

data['filtered_text'] = data['text'].astype(str).apply(lambda line: [token for token in word_tokenize(line) if token not in stoplist])
```

## In Long

Please see [Why is my NLTK function slow when processing the DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe) for more detailed explanation on:

- tokenize text in a dataframe
- remove stopwords
- other related cleaning processes

---

For better, twitter text processing

```
pip3 install -U nltk[twitter]
```

Then use this:

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

import pandas as pd

word_tokenize = TweetTokenizer().tokenize

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english'))

data = pd.read_csv("Test_file.csv")

data['filtered_text'] = data['text'].astype(str).apply(lambda line: [token for token in word_tokenize(line) if token not in stoplist])
```

Comment: may you please explain bit more to me how did you remove the error "unhashable type: 'list'" Thanks in advance.