# How to I put the result of chunk into csv columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nltk

I have a csv file and i already chunked one of the columns in it and wanted to put the result of my chunks into separate columns in the csv file, by converting them into list using this code, but i kept on getting this error

IndexError: list index out of range

```
tag_count_df = pd.DataFrame(news['entityrecognition'].map(lambda x: Counter(tag[1] for tag in x)).to_list())
```

Below are my current code,

```
news=pd.read_csv("news.csv")

news['tokenize'] = news.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['STORY']), axis=1)


news['pos_tags'] = news.apply(lambda row: nltk.pos_tag(row['tokenize']), axis=1)

news['entityrecog']=news.apply(lambda row: nltk.ne_chunk(row['pos_tags']), axis=1)

tag_count_df = pd.DataFrame(news['entityrecognition'].map(lambda x: Counter(tag[1] for tag in x)).to_list())

news=pd.concat([news, tag_count_df], axis=1).fillna(0).drop(['entityrecognition'], axis=1)

news.to_csv("news.csv")
```

Sample of my news.csv

```
ID STORY
1  Washington, a police officer James...
```

The result i wanted

```
ID  STORY                                       PERSON  NE   NP  NN VB  GE
1   Washington, a police officer James...        1      0    0   0   0   1
```

Comment: not too familiar with map and counter but should it not be tag[0] since you call only one column?

Comment: @kempie the tag is to count how many person, VBZ, VB it is in the sentence

Comment: @if i did tag[0] it would count the no of word instead, like 

washington  =   1
a  =1
police =1

Comment: I think you will get a faster answer if you can include a sample of your input news.csv in a pandas ready format. Ps. Do you then still get the Error: IndexError: list index out of range?

Comment: @kempie edited my question, and yes is till got the error

Comment: This is all a bit new to me but It seems that nltk.ne_chunk returns tree structures. I'm not a 100% sure what your expected outcome should look like for all scenario's and only tested it on the string "Washington, a police officer James" but it seems like retrieving the list labels are what you are after. Try changing the code to: tag_count_df = pd.DataFrame(df['entityrecog'].map(lambda x: Counter(tag.label() for tag in x if type(tag) is nltk.Tree)).to_list())

Comment: Also, I guessed that the column name 'entityrecognition' should actually be 'entityrecog'.

Comment: That multiple `.apply` looping across the whole dataframe again and again will end up with really slow code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe