# Why is the number of stem from NLTK Stemmer outputs different from expected output?

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, stemming

I have to perform Stemming on a text. The questions are as follows :

1. Tokenize all the words given in `tc`. The word should contain alphabets or numbers or underscore. Store the tokenized list of words in `tw`
2. Convert all the words into lowercase. Store the result into the variable `tw`
3. Remove all the stop words from the unique set of `tw`. Store the result into the variable `fw`
4. Stem each word present in `fw` with PorterStemmer, and store the result in the list `psw`

Below is my code :

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem  import PorterStemmer,LancasterStemmer

pattern = r'\w+';
tw= nltk.regexp_tokenize(tc,pattern);
tw= [word.lower() for word in tw];
stop_word = set(stopwords.words('english'));
fw= [w for w in tw if not w in stop_word];
#print(sorted(filteredwords));
porter = PorterStemmer();
psw = [porter.stem(word) for word in fw];
print(sorted(psw));
```

My code works perfectly with all the provided testcases in hand-on but it fails only for the below test case where

> tc = "I inadvertently went to See's Candy last week (I was in the mall looking for phone repair), and as it turns out, See's Candy now charges a dollar -- a full dollar -- for even the simplest of their wee confection offerings. I bought two chocolate lollipops and two chocolate-caramel-almond things. The total cost was four-something. I mean, the candies were tasty and all, but let's be real: A Snickers bar is fifty cents. After this dollar-per-candy revelation, I may not find myself wandering dreamily back into a See's Candy any time soon."

My Output is :

> ['almond', 'back', 'bar', 'bought', **'candi', 'candi'**, 'caramel', 'cent', 'charg', 'chocol', 'confect', 'cost', 'dollar', 'dreamili', 'even', 'fifti', 'find', 'four', 'full', 'inadvert', 'last', 'let', 'lollipop', 'look', 'mall', 'may', 'mean', 'offer', 'per', 'phone', 'real', 'repair', 'revel', 'see', 'simplest', 'snicker', 'someth', 'soon', 'tasti', 'thing', 'time', 'total', 'turn', 'two', 'wander', 'wee', 'week', 'went']

Expected Output is :

> ['almond', 'back', 'bar', 'bought', **'candi', 'candi', 'candi'**, 'caramel', 'cent', 'charg', 'chocol', 'confect', 'cost', 'dollar', 'dreamili', 'even', 'fifti', 'find', 'four', 'full', 'inadvert', 'last', 'let', 'lollipop', 'look', 'mall', 'may', 'mean', 'offer', 'per', 'phone', 'real', 'repair', 'revel', 'see', 'simplest', 'snicker', 'someth', 'soon', 'tasti', 'thing', 'time', 'total', 'turn', 'two', 'wander', 'wee', 'week', 'went']

> The difference is the occurrence of 'Candi'

Looking help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: What code produced the ‘expected output’? Did it use the same versions of everything you are using?

Comment: The Expected Output reflected when I executed my code. I cannot see the code which got the expected output.
Yes, I believe the versions are same. AS the hands-on assessment is on web IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem  import PorterStemmer,LancasterStemmer

pattern = r'\w+';
tw= nltk.regexp_tokenize(tc,pattern);
tw= [word.lower() for word in tw];
unique_tw = set(tw); #Unique Set of Tokenized words(See Your Step3)
stop_word = set(stopwords.words('english'));
fw= [w for w in unique_tw if not w in stop_word];# Remove stopwords from unique_tw
porter = PorterStemmer();
psw = [porter.stem(word) for word in fw];
print(sorted(psw));
```

As step 3 is: **Remove all the stop words from the unique set of tw.**

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the Title case and lower case of the word "Candy"

> I inadvertently went to See's Candy last week (I was in the mall looking for phone repair), and as it turns out, See's Candy now charges a dollar -- a full dollar -- for even the simplest of their wee confection offerings. I bought two chocolate lollipops and two chocolate-caramel-almond things. The total cost was four-something. I mean, the candies were tasty and all, but let's be real: A Snickers bar is fifty cents. After this dollar-per-**candy** revelation, I may not find myself wandering dreamily back into a See's Candy any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

```py
   
    stopword = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    pattern = "\w+"

    tokenizedwords = nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent,pattern)

    filteredwords = [word for word in tokenizedwords if word.lower() not in stopword]

    porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    porterstemmedwords = [porter.stem(word.lower()) for word in set(filteredwords)]

    lancaster = nltk.LancasterStemmer()
    lancasterstemmedwords = [lancaster.stem(word.lower()) for word in set(filteredwords)]

    net_lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatizedwords = [net_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in set(filteredwords)]

    return porterstemmedwords,lancasterstemmedwords,lemmatizedwords
```

please try the above one. dont convert the word to small letter in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take unique set of words before converting tw into lower case.
That is like this

```
tw= nltk.regexp_tokenize(tc,pattern);
tw = set(tw)
tw= [word.lower() for word in tw];
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, don't iterate through the text multiple times, see [Why is my NLTK function slow when processing the DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769818/why-is-my-nltk-function-slow-when-processing-the-dataframe)

Do this instead and you only iterate through your data/text once:

```
import re

from nltk import word_tokenize, regexp_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem  import PorterStemmer

stop_word = set(stopwords.words('english'))
porter = PorterStemmer()

text = "I inadvertently went to See's Candy last week (I was in the mall looking for phone repair), and as it turns out, See's Candy now charges a dollar -- a full dollar -- for even the simplest of their wee confection offerings. I bought two chocolate lollipops and two chocolate-caramel-almond things. The total cost was four-something. I mean, the candies were tasty and all, but let's be real: A Snickers bar is fifty cents. After this dollar-per-candy revelation, I may not find myself wandering dreamily back into a See's Candy any time soon."

signature = [porter.stem(word.lower()) 
             for word in regexp_tokenize(text,r'\w+') 
             if word.lower() not in stop_word]
```

Next, lets check against the expected output:

```
signature = [(word, porter.stem(word.lower())) for word in regexp_tokenize(text,r'\w+')]

expected = ['almond', 'back', 'bar', 'bought', 'candi', 'candi', 'candi', 'caramel', 'cent', 'charg', 'chocol', 'confect', 'cost', 'dollar', 'dreamili', 'even', 'fifti', 'find', 'four', 'full', 'inadvert', 'last', 'let', 'lollipop', 'look', 'mall', 'may', 'mean', 'offer', 'per', 'phone', 'real', 'repair', 'revel', 'see', 'simplest', 'snicker', 'someth', 'soon', 'tasti', 'thing', 'time', 'total', 'turn', 'two', 'wander', 'wee', 'week', 'went']

sorted(signature) == expected  # -> False
```

[out]:

```
False
```

That's not a good sign, lets find which terms are missing:

```
# If item in signature but not in expected.
len(set(signature).difference(expected)) == 0  # -> True
# If item in expected but not in signature. 
len(set(expected).difference(signature)) == 0  # -> True
```

In that case, lets check the counts:

```
print(len(signature), len(expected))
```

[out]:

```
57 49
```

Seems like your expected output is missing quite a few items. Checking through:

```
from collections import Counter
counter_signature = Counter(signature)
counter_expected = Counter(expected)


for word, count in counter_signature.items():
    # If the count in expected is different.
    expected_count = counter_expected[word]
    if count != expected_count: 
        print(word, count, expected_count)
```

It seems like not only  `candi` has different count!

[out]:

```
see 3 1
candi 5 3
dollar 3 1
two 2 1
chocol 2 1
```

It looks like the signature (i.e. processed text) contains a lot more counts than the expected from the expected output in the question. So most probably the test you have is not counting things right =)