# NLP Stemming and Lemmatization using Regular expression tokenization

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Define a function called `performStemAndLemma`, which takes a parameter. The first parameter, `textcontent`, is a string. The function definition code stub is given in the editor. Perform the following specified tasks:

1.Tokenize all the words given in `textcontent`. The word should contain alphabets or numbers or underscore. Store the tokenized list of words in `tokenizedwords`. (Hint: Use regexp_tokenize)

2. Convert all the words into lowercase. Store the result into the variable `tokenizedwords`.
3. Remove all the stop words from the unique set of `tokenizedwords`. Store the result into the variable `filteredwords`. (Hint: Use stopwords corpora)
4. Stem each word present in `filteredwords` with PorterStemmer, and store the result in the list `porterstemmedwords`.
5. Stem each word present in `filteredwords` with LancasterStemmer, and store the result in the list `lancasterstemmedwords`.
6. Lemmatize each word present in `filteredwords` with WordNetLemmatizer, and store the result in the list `lemmatizedwords`.

Return `porterstemmedwords`, `lancasterstemmedwords`, `lemmatizedwords` variables from the function.

My code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    # Write your code here
    #Step 1
    tokenizedword = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(textcontent, pattern = '\w*', gaps = False)
    #Step 2
    tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedword if x != '']
    #Step 3
    unique_tokenizedwords = set(tokenizedwords)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
    filteredwords = []
    for x in unique_tokenizedwords:
        if x not in stop_words:
            filteredwords.append(x)
    #Steps 4, 5 , 6
    ps = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
    ls = nltk.stem.LancasterStemmer()
    wnl = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    porterstemmedwords =[]
    lancasterstemmedwords = []
    lemmatizedwords = []
    for x in filteredwords:
        porterstemmedwords.append(ps.stem(x))
        lancasterstemmedwords.append(ls.stem(x))
        lemmatizedwords.append(wnl.lemmatize(x))
    return porterstemmedwords, lancasterstemmedwords, lemmatizedwords
```

Still the program is not working fine. Not passing the 2 test cases. Highlight the mistake in above code and provide alternate solution for the same.

Comment: please specify your question. What are the test cases that failed? Which step failed? What output did you expect?

Comment: Input: I inadvertently went to See's Candy last week (I was in the mall looking for phone repair), and as it turns out, See's Candy now charges a dollar -- a full dollar -- for even the simplest of their wee confection offerings. I bought two chocolate lollipops and two chocolate-caramel-almond things. The total cost was four-something. I mean, the candies were tasty and all, but let's be real: A Snickers bar is fifty cents. After this dollar-per-candy revelation, I may not find myself wandering dreamily back into a See's Candy any time soon.

Comment: My output:['almond', 'back', 'bar', 'bought', 'candi', 'candi', 'caramel', 'cent', 'cent', 'cent', 'charg', 'chocol', 'confect', 'cost', 'dollar', 'dreamili', 'even', 'fifti', 'find', 'four', 'full', 'inadvert', 'last', 'let', 'lollipop', 'look', 'mall', 'may', 'mean', 'offer', 'per', 'phone', 'real', 'repair', 'revel', 'see', 'simplest', 'snicker', 'someth', 'soon', 'tasti', 'thing', 'time', 'total', 'turn', 'two', 'wander', 'wee', 'week', 'went'] Porter Stemming o/p and see candi appearing two times

Comment: Expected output:['almond', 'back', 'bar', 'bought', 'candi', 'candi', 'candi', 'caramel', 'cent', 'charg', 'chocol', 'confect', 'cost', 'dollar', 'dreamili', 'even', 'fifti', 'find', 'four', 'full', 'inadvert', 'last', 'let', 'lollipop', 'look', 'mall', 'may', 'mean', 'offer', 'per', 'phone', 'real', 'repair', 'revel', 'see', 'simplest', 'snicker', 'someth', 'soon', 'tasti', 'thing', 'time', 'total', 'turn', 'two', 'wander', 'wee', 'week', 'went']
Porter stemming o/p see candi appearing three times

Comment: The issue is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626878/why-is-the-number-of-stem-from-nltk-stemmer-outputs-different-from-expected-outp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    # Write your code here
    import re
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    from nltk import PorterStemmer, LancasterStemmer
    
    pattern =  r'\w*' 
    tokenizedwords = nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent, pattern, gaps=False)
    tokenizedwords = [words for words in tokenizedwords if words !='']
    
    uniquetokenizedwords = set(tokenizedwords)
    tokenizedwords = [words.lower() for words in uniquetokenizedwords if words !='']
    
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filteredwords = [words for words in tokenizedwords if words not in stop_words]

    porterstemmedwords = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    porterstemmedwords =[porterstemmedwords.stem(words) for words in filteredwords]
    
    lancasterstemmedwords = nltk.LancasterStemmer()
    lancasterstemmedwords =[lancasterstemmedwords.stem(words) for words in filteredwords]
    
    wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatizedwords = [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in filteredwords ]
    
    return porterstemmedwords, lancasterstemmedwords, lemmatizedwords
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the expected output is to consider uppercase and lowercase words as seperate tokens. Hence you should fetch all unique words before converting all of them to lower case. I hope the following code should work.

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    # Write your code here
    #Step 1
    tokenizedword = nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent, pattern = r'\w*', gaps = False)
    #Step 2
    tokenizedwords = [y for y in tokenizedword if y != '']
    unique_tokenizedwords = set(tokenizedwords)
    tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in unique_tokenizedwords if x != '']
    #Step 3
    #unique_tokenizedwords = set(tokenizedwords)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
    filteredwords = []
    for x in tokenizedwords:
        if x not in stop_words:
            filteredwords.append(x)
    #Steps 4, 5 , 6
    ps = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
    ls = nltk.stem.LancasterStemmer()
    wnl = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    porterstemmedwords =[]
    lancasterstemmedwords = []
    lemmatizedwords = []
    for x in filteredwords:
        porterstemmedwords.append(ps.stem(x))
        lancasterstemmedwords.append(ls.stem(x))
        lemmatizedwords.append(wnl.lemmatize(x))
    return porterstemmedwords, lancasterstemmedwords, lemmatizedwords
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach below cleared all the test cases for me

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    # Write your code here
    lancaster = nltk.LancasterStemmer()
    porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    tokens2_3 = nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent,  r'\w+')
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokenisedwords=[words for words in set(tokens2_3) if not words.lower() in  stop_words ]
    #print(tokenizedwords)
    return [porter.stem(word.lower()) for word in set(tokenisedwords)],[lancaster.stem(word.lower()) for word in set(tokenisedwords)],[wnl.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in set(tokenisedwords)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Just import `stopwords` after defining the function as above. The rest of the code remains the same.

Comment: then i dont have any idea

Answer (score 1):

from nltk import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer, LancasterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
# Write your code here
tokenizedword = nltk.tokenize.regexp_tokenize(textcontent, pattern = '\w*', gaps = False)

```
tokenizedwords = [x.lower() for x in tokenizedword if x != '']

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
filteredwords = [x for x in set(tokenizedwords) if x not in stop_words]

ps = PorterStemmer()
ls = LancasterStemmer()
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
porterstemmedwords =[ps.stem(x) for x in filteredwords]
lancasterstemmedwords = [ls.stem(x) for x in filteredwords]
lemmatizedwords = [wnl.lemmatize(x) for x in filteredwords]

return porterstemmedwords, lancasterstemmedwords, lemmatizedwords
```

Answer (score 1):

'''This worked for me'''

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import PorterStemmer
from nltk import LancasterStemmer

def performStemAndLemma(textcontent):
    pattern =r'\w+'
    tokenizewords=nltk.regexp_tokenize(textcontent,pattern)
    tokenizewords = [w.lower() for w in set(tokenizewords)]
    stopper = stopwords.words("english")
    filteredwords = [w for w in tokenizewords if w not in stopper]
    porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    lancaster = nltk.LancasterStemmer()
    porterstemmedwords = [porter.stem(w) for w in filteredwords]
    lancasterstemmedwords = [lancaster.stem(w) for w in filteredwords]
    wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatizedwords = [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in filteredwords]
    return porterstemmedwords, lancasterstemmedwords, lemmatizedwords
```