# extract pos_tag_sents from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, part-of-speech

following the advice from the thread [How to apply pos_tag_sents() to pandas dataframe efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674573/how-to-apply-pos-tag-sents-to-pandas-dataframe-efficiently) I run the code to identify different pos for the text in one of my variables.

Now that I managed to create the column of interest - sub['POS'] - how do I extract my relevant information - all the NN - and create a column for each of them?

```
print(sub['POS'])

5     [(e-mail, JJ), (new, JJ), (delhi, NN), ((, (),...
4     [(bangladesh, JJ), (garment, NN), (unions, NNS...
41    [(listen, VB), (blaze, NN), (wrecks, NNS), (te...
10    [(11:49, CD), (am, VBP), (,, ,), (september, V...
17    [(listen, JJ), (two, CD), (events, NNS), (plan...
```

as an output, I would like a new column (here as 'NN'), that contains all the NN for each row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["delhi", 
                   "garment" , 
                   "blaze", 
                   NaN], columns=['NN'])
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your expected output, please?

Comment: I added how I would like the output - a new column where each row contains all the NN of the sub['POS'] series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am assuming you have one column in the dataframe where each row is a list of tuples. Please correct me if I am wrong. From that column you want to create new columns for each 'Tag'. Do you think following is what will achieve what you want to do?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"line":[[('e-mail', 'JJ'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('delhi', 'NN')]]})

def extract_pos(line,pos):
    return [word[0] for word in line if word[1] == pos]

df['NN'] = [extract_pos(line,'NN') for line in df['line']]
df['JJ'] = [extract_pos(line,'JJ') for line in df['line']]
```

This way you can add many column as you want and the result might look as some thing like following.

[image]

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: Great :) happy coding!